# Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values

Tags: banco-de-dados, r, data.frame, log, transform

Tenho uma variável contínua cujo `n=15000` observações e apresenta 451 NA's. Ao rodar o `qqnorm` para avaliação da normalidade, verifiquei que a mesma não apresenta normalidade e por isso apliquei uma transformação logarítmica. Entretanto, ao rodar o `qqnorm` com a variável log-transformada, o gráfico não foi plotado e apareceu a seguinte mensagem de erro:

`Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values`

Abaixo o script na ordem explicada acima:

```
> summary(data1$microalb)
Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.     NA's 
0.0000   0.3474   0.5042   1.3220   0.8426 308.0000      451 

> qqnorm(data1$microalb) # inspecionando a normalidade
> log.microalb=log(data1$microalb) # aplicando transformação logarítmica
> qqnorm(log.microalb, main="Q-Q Plot - Log microalb", xlab="Quantis Teóricos", ylab= "Quantis Observados")
```

Excluí os NA's da variável, mas o erro persistiu, logo provavelmente o problema não está nos missings. O que poderia estar impossibilitando a geração do qqnorm com os dados log-transformados?

OBS.: apliquei a mesma transformação em outras variáveis e não houve problema, apenas nessa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O mínimo de `data1$microalb` é zero. Portanto, `log(min(data1$microalb)) = -Inf`. Rode `summary(log.microalb)` para confirmar isto.

Exclua as informações infinitas do teu conjunto de dados. Uma maneira comum de fazer isto é adicionando 1 ao vetor que deve ser plotado, pois `log(1) = 0`. Portanto,

```
qqnorm(log.microalb+1, main="Q-Q Plot - Log microalb", 
  xlab="Quantis Teóricos", ylab= "Quantis Observados")
```

deve resolver o teu problema.

Se tu quiser apenas remover as observações infinitas do teu conjunto de dados, rode

```
qqnorm(log.microalb[!is.infinite(log.microalb)])
```

embora esta solução não seja a mais comum na literatura. O procedimento mais utilizado é justamente o anterior, somando 1 aos dados.

Comment: Oi Marcus, obrigada pela sugestão. Entretanto tentei rodar das duas maneiras sugeridas e dessa vez aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:           
Error in qqnorm.default(log.microalb[!is.infinite(log.microalb)]) : 
  y is empty or has only NAs
Error in qqnorm.default(log.microalb + 1, main = "Q-Q Plot - Log microalb",  : 
  y is empty or has only NAs

Comment: `log.microalb` existe? Qual o output de `summary(log.microalb)`?

Comment: Sim, existe:                                                                                                     
  > summary(log.microalb)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
   -Inf -1.0570 -0.6847    -Inf -0.1713  5.7300     451

Comment: Marcus, o seguinte plot funcionou: qqnorm(log.microalb[!is.infinite(log.microalb)]) Entretanto, o seguinte plot apresentou uma mensagem de erro: > qqnorm(log.microalb.mgdl+1, main="Q-Q Plot - Log microalb.mgdl", 
+        xlab="Quantis Teóricos", ylab= "Quantis Observados")
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values De qualquer forma, obrigada pelas sugestões, a segunda funcionou.